# Apex upsert duplicate external id specified error

Tags: apex, upsert

Long time listener, first time caller (and apex-er).  I have a class to copy subscription items to a custom ARR Sub Line object; from there I can use out of the box rollups to pull my ARR onto accounts and contracts.  Currently we have some process builders and flows and such; deletes are a bit of a problem and hoping to just have it cleaner in general.

I'm having an issue with upserting - using external id field Related_Record_ID__c on the custom object.

```
First exception on row 0 with id a32W000000DLa53IAD; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, SubscriptionTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a12W00000079HxwIAE; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, Duplicate external id specified: a32W000000DLa51IAD: [Related_Record_ID__c] ()
```

I feel like I'm probably missing something dumb, but not sure...  any advice would be appreciated.

```
public class SubscriptionTriggerHandler {
    
    public static List<ARR_Sub_Line_Item__c> asl = new List<ARR_Sub_Line_Item__c>();
    //public static List<ARR_Sub_Line_Item__c> aslTrash = new List<ARR_Sub_Line_Item__c>();

    
    public static void onSubscriptionUpsert(List<SBQQ__Subscription__c> subs, List<SBQQ__Subscription__c> subsOld)
    {
        Set<ID> delIDs = new set <id>();
        for (SBQQ__Subscription__c sub : subs)
        {            
            //create/update ARR Sub Line record for non 0 values
            IF(sub.Product_Charge_Type__c=='Recurring' && sub.Annualized_Price__c<>0){
                string BrandClean=sub.Product_Brand__c.replace(',','');
                asl.add(New ARR_Sub_Line_Item__c(Account__c=sub.SBQQ__Account__c, Contract__c=sub.SBQQ__Contract__c, 
                                                 Contract_Active__c=sub.Count_Towards_ARR__c,
                                                 CurrencyIsoCode=sub.CurrencyIsoCode,Parent_Product_Code__c=sub.Parent_Product_Code__c,
                                                 Parent_Product_Is_Module__c=sub.Parent_Product_Is_Module__c,
                                                 Product_Brand__c=BrandClean, 
                                                 Subscription__c=sub.Id,Related_Record_ID__c=sub.Id,Recurring_Value__c=sub.Annualized_Price__c
                                                ));
            }
            //if value has been updated to 0 we want to remove the ARR Sub Line record
            ELSE IF (sub.Product_Charge_Type__c=='Recurring' && sub.Annualized_Price__c==0 && trigger.isUpdate)
            {
                delIDs.add(sub.Id);
            }
        }
        if(asl.size()>0){
            upsert asl Related_Record_ID__c;
        }
        if(delIDs.size()>0) {
            asl=[Select ID, Related_Record_ID__c from ARR_Sub_Line_Item__c where Related_Record_ID__c IN:delIDs];
            delete asl;
        }
    }
    
    public static void onSubscriptionDeleteUnDelete(List<SBQQ__Subscription__c> subs,string deleteVar)
    {
        List<Id>subIds = new List<Id>();
        Map<Id, SBQQ__Subscription__c> subMap = new Map<Id, SBQQ__Subscription__c>();
        for (SBQQ__Subscription__c sub : subs)
        {
            subIds.add(sub.Id);
        }
        if(deleteVar=='delete'){
            asl=[Select ID, Related_Record_ID__c from ARR_Sub_Line_Item__c where Related_Record_ID__c IN:subIds];
        }
        if(deleteVar=='undelete'){
            asl=[Select ID, Related_Record_ID__c from ARR_Sub_Line_Item__c where Related_Record_ID__c IN:subIds and IsDeleted=TRUE ALL ROWS]; 
        }
        
        if(asl.size()>0){
            System.debug('asl size is '+asl.size());
            if(deleteVar=='delete'){ delete asl;}
            if(deleteVar=='undelete'){ undelete asl;}
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems relatively clear that this structure allows you to insert only one line item per related record. What exactly is the question though? The error message is enforcing the design your code seems structured to intentionally put in place.

Comment: Well I'd kind of like it to run without an error...

Comment: But your code is structured such that you clearly expect only one line item per related record. You have to clarify if you want that behavior to hold.

Comment: Yes, I only want one item per related record.  When CPQ generates the contract it throws the error.  I thought that with the upsert against the external key it would just negate the duplicate issue?

Comment: Not if you have the same key twice in the same transaction.

Comment: Ok, so that is the problem...  Do you have any suggestion on what is wrong?